# Setting Environment variables for nmake through ANT for entire build

Tags: ant

How can we Set Environment variables for nmake through ANT for **entire build**?

Answer (score 0):

Ant can't **set** environment variables directly. It can read them using the [property](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) task.

However, you can use the [exec](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task to execute your operating system's environment variable-setting command. Since you're using `nmake` I assume you're on Windows, which offers the [setx](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) command for this purpose.

```
<exec executable="setx.exe">
  <arg line="_car_park South"/>
  <arg line="/m"/>
</exec>
```

The `/m` flag sets the `_car_park` variable to `South` in the machine's environment (`setx` defaults to the user's environment).